# La liaison dans « il n'en est rien »

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

D'après ce que je comprend il y a une liaison obligatoire entre « en » et « est » dans la lecture de « il n'en est rien ». ([Quora](https://fr.quora.com/Quelle-est-la-bonne-formule-il-nen-est-rien-ou-il-nen-nest-rien-ou-il-en-est-rien-ou-il-en-nest-rien), [Français-Facile- here4u](https://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=100366))

Je trouve l'enchainement de syllabes qui résulte de cette prononciation assez désagréable ; on y décèle  même de façon ambigüe le texte « il n'en naît rien » ; je suis sujet à une certaine propension à ne pas faire une liaison totale—« il nenne est rien », « en » comme dans « pente »,  e final  muet. Cette prononciation-ci est donc différente de « il n'en hait rien »).  Est-ce que l'on connaitrait une prosodie, régionale ou autre, dans laquelle  cette liaison incomplète serait connue, acceptable ou une tendance ?

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî La seule véritable ambigüité c'est celle qui résulte du fait que la prononciation est la même que celle de  « il n'en n'est rien » ; on a une impression de particule négative, du moins c'est ce que ça me fait. L'autre ambigüité (« nait ») ne se sent pas (il faut y penser pour la sentir). Ma question cherche surtout à savoir si par le biais de ce principe, auquel après tout d'autres peuvent avoir eu recours, il n'existerait pas une telle pratique dans la langue (de portée très restreinte, évidemment).

Comment: L'API selon _Wiktionnaire_ : [il n‿ɑ̃ n‿ɛ ʁjɛ̃](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_n%E2%80%99en_est_rien).

Answer (score 3):

La seule évolution courante est la chute du *ne* pour arriver à ***Il en est rien*** mais la liaison entre *en* et *rien* y reste obligatoire.

Je ne connais pas de cas où la prononciation suggérée (insertion d'une légère pause au milieu de la liaison) soit répandue. Je ne vois d'ailleurs pas non plus ce qui peut de déplaire dans ce type de liaison qui est très courant en français: *en est*, *on est*, *on n'est*, *on nait*, *en naît*, *en nez* ...

Une séquence où ce type de liaison est interdit est : ***En et** rien sont deux pronoms.*

Comment: Je sais bien que cette liaison  est obligatoire, et je ne vois pas comment ne pas la faire  au vu de l'uniformité avec laquelle le type de liaison qu'elle représente est utilisé, sauf au moyen de cette liaison « incomplète » dont je parle ; c'est une solution qui néanmoins n'est pas réaliste (le moins d'exceptions, le plus facile la langue). J'ai toujours le choix de me passer d'utiliser cette forme.

Comment: *Le plus facile la langue* fleure l'anglicisme... ;-)

Comment: Ellipse des verbes dans une parenthèse, pas possible ? (le moins il y a d'exceptions, le plus facile est la langue)

Comment: Pourquoi j'hésite entre _le_ et _la_ dans cette tournure ?

Comment: @LPH Rien n'est impossible; les langues vivantes, justement, le sont. Je relevais simplement l'anglicisme.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî *Moins d'exceptions dans une langue découvriras, plus facile la trouveras* :-)